# async / await best way on REST API Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest

I've a question because I'm a noob in Ruby but I need to develop an API.

I ask you to understand better how to implement the async/await. For example here :

**members_controller.rb**

```
 #GET /members
# Get all the members 
def index
  begin
    render json: Member.get_all_members
  rescue => error
    render json: {message: "An error occurs during the get all members", status: 404, error: error.message}
  end
end
```

And the model **member.rb**

```
  # Get all members
  #
  def self.get_all_members
    begin
      return self.all
    rescue => error
      raise "Exception thrown #{error.message}"
    end
  end
```

I want to manage well the await/async response.

Don't hesitate to send me good documentation or whatever which can help me.

I'm so lost because I come from the .NET framework env ! ahah.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The Fetch or Axios call with async and await is on the client side ; not in the API. So you have to write it in javascript (for example) in the application that will consume your API. As such, your code seems fine. As a side-comment : Ruby on Rails is an overkill for an API. Please check Sinatra or Roda with Sequel.

Comment: thanks for your comment @thiebo. It's strange to don't have an await/async to call a database. Very very strange. And can me explain why Rails API is overkill ? It's the API framework so... I'm interesting by your suggestion !

Comment: The question is: why would you do an async function to call a database? Concerning RoR versus Sinatra versus other frameworks: it's just an opinion. Don't bother.

Comment: => Scalability / performance.
When you make I/O calls - database queries, file reading, reading from HTTP etc- the thread that is handling the current HTTP request is just waiting.
It’s just waiting for a result to come back from the operating system.

Performing a database query, for example, ultimately asks the operating system to connect to the database, send a message and get a message in return. And so just to perform the app.

Comment: While I understand your POV and async here would generated many more things for you to handle. If want a more simple and excellent option look for phoenixframework its based on elixir. Its not oop, but functional programing.

Comment: ?? What ? ahah. all the language does async/await. Java, C#, nodejs etc in backend so I think Ruby too ahah. I'll search.

Comment: ruby language and rails framework do not support `async/await` . meanwhile you might as take look at https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby

Answer (score 2):

You can try to explore [async-ruby](https://brunosutic.com/blog/async-ruby) & [load_async](https://pawelurbanek.com/rails-load-async)